# Using a loop in a CUDA graph

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, scheduling, cuda-graphs

I have kernel A, B, and C which need to be executed sequentially.

A->B->C

They are executed in a *while* loop until some condition will be met.

```
while(predicate) {
    A->B->C
}
```

The *while* loop may be executed from 3 to 2000 times - information about a fact that a loop should stopped is produced by kernel C.

As the execution is related to multiple invocations of relatively  small kernels CUDA Graph sounds like a good idea. However, CUDA graph implementation I have seen are all linear  or tree-like without loops.

Generally, if the loop is not possible, the long chain of kernels of the length 2000 with possibility of early stop invoked from kernel C would be also OK. However, is it possible to stop the graph execution in some position by the call from inside of the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA graphs have no conditionals. A vertex of the graph is visited/executed when its predecessors are complete, and that's that. So, fundamentally, you cannot do this with a CUDA graph.

What can you do?

1. Have a smaller graph for the loop iteration, and repeatedly schedule it.
2. Have A, B and C start their execution by checking the loop predicate - and skip all work if it holds. With that being the case, you can schedule many instances of A->B->C->A->B->C etc - which, starting at some point, will  do nothing.
3. Don't rely on the CUDA graphs API. It's not a general-purpose parallel execution mechanism. :-(

Comment: Thanks!  and Would it be possible to use  events for the idea 2 - I am afraid that if the kernels will run continously but doing real work only some small section of time  it will lead to reduction of occupancy of the working kernel - I am thinking about those https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html

Comment: @JakubMitura: Within a kernel, you can't work with events. What you can do is have a flag in global device memory (or in device-accessible host memory), and read that.